# Is there application Scope in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, application-scope

I saw 'application' scope in the following blog. Is it true?

http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-bean-scope-example-using-scope-annotation-and-xml-for-singleton-prototype-request-session-global-session-and-application-scope-with-scoped-proxy

Because, as per my surfing, I got to know spring has only the below 5 scopes. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

1. Singleton
2. Prototype
3. Request
4. Session
5. Global Session

Comment: so what would be the difference between application scope and singleton scope?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a section on the official doc which is related to the bean scopes:

- [7.5 Bean scopes](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes)

Basically, they define the next:

> **singleton** (Default) Scopes a single bean definition to a single object instance per Spring IoC container.
>
> **prototype**
>   Scopes a single bean definition to any number of object instances.
>
> **request**
>   Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a single HTTP request; that is, each HTTP request has its own instance of a bean created off the back of a single bean definition. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.
>
> **session**
>   Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of an HTTP Session. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.
>
> **globalSession**
>   Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a global HTTP Session. Typically only valid when used in a Portlet context. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.
>
> **application**
>   Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a ServletContext. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.
>
> **websocket**
>   Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a WebSocket. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.

---

Furthermore, as Spring 3.0 exists other scope  **thread scope** but is not registered by default, moreover you could even create your own scope:

> As of Spring 3.0, a thread scope is available, but is not registered
>   by default. For more information, see the documentation for
>   SimpleThreadScope. For instructions on how to register this or any
>   another custom scope, see the section called “Using a custom scope”.

There is a section which explains how to define your custom scope:

- [7.5.5 Custom scopes](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-custom)

---

Respect to `Application scope`, they define it as next:

> The Spring container creates a new instance of the AppPreferences bean
>   by using the appPreferences bean definition once for the entire web
>   application. That is, the appPreferences bean is scoped at the
>   ServletContext level, stored as a regular ServletContext attribute.

It also explains the difference between a Spring singleton bean:

> This is somewhat similar to a Spring singleton bean but differs in two
>   important ways: It is a singleton per ServletContext, not per Spring
>   'ApplicationContext' (for which there may be several in any given web
>   application), and it is actually exposed and therefore visible as a
>   ServletContext attribute

So in case you are looking to use with XML:

```
<bean id="apps" class="com.App" scope="application"/>
```

Or annotation:

```
@ApplicationScope
@Component
public class App {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**application**
Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a ServletContext. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.

Follow the link for more details: 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes